# how DenseVector to convert to DenseMatrix

Tags: scala, matrix, scala-breeze

I have data for N rows xM rows `DenseVector[DenseVector[Double]]` (or `DenseMatrix[DenseMatrix[Double]]`) and want to convert this object into an NxM's `DenseMatrix` object

```
DenseVector(DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0), DenseVector(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0), DenseVector(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0), DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0))
```

converted single DenseMatrix object

```
 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0
11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0
11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0
 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0
```

Here is the test code, It can't executed.

```
object BreezeTest extends App {
    val mx = Array(Array(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0),Array(5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0)),Array(Array(11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0),Array(15.0,16.0,17.0,18.0)))

    val my = Array(Array(0,1),Array(1,0))
    val myND =DenseMatrix(my:_*)
    val newND = myND.map(s=>DenseVector(mx(s).flatten)).flatten()   // here is 4d array,It's difficult process,so try flat to 2d matrix 
    println(newND)
    println(DenseMatrix.vertcat(newND:_*)

}
```

Comment: What is `DenseVector`? What is `DenseMatrix`?

Comment: What is the initial data representation. Do you have your data as Arrays... or other Collection?, because you don´t need to build DenseVectors to build a DenseMatrix, you can build directly the Matrix

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, it's possible to create DenseMatrix directly, but it won't solve my problem. Because I have a few matrices that do some transformations between each other and end up in this situation, I want to see how I can do sth. resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

```
val mx = DenseVector(DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0), 
                     DenseVector(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0), 
                     DenseVector(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0), 
                     DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0))
   
val m = 4
val n = 8
new DenseMatrix(4, 8, mx(1 until mx.size).foldLeft(mx(0)){ case (acc, v) => 
    DenseVector.vertcat(acc, v)
}.toArray)
```